# Passing std::left as an argument

Tags: c++, io, stream, output, manipulators

I have a function that display something, where the character positioning can be different. Function looks like this:

```
void display(std::ostream & stream, std::ios_base & positioning);
```

However, when I try to call this function like this

```
display_header(std::cout, std::left);
```

I get the following error

```
error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'std::ios_base' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'std::ios_base &(std::ios_base &)'
```

I don't understand why `std::cout` can be passed just fine, but `std::left` refuses to do so. Also how is `lvalue reference to type 'std::ios_base'` different from `lvalue reference to type 'std::ios_base'` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like most [stream manipulators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip), `std::left` is a function, not a variable.  `display` would need to be changed to

```
void display(std::ostream & stream, std::ios_base &(*positioning)(std::ios_base &));
```

In order to accept `left`, `right`, `internal`, or any other manipulator of the type `std::ios_base &(std::ios_base &)`.